# Synchronous Network request inside foreach and subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

What I need is to get a data from one api and than send it to other and append the values.

I've tried using async await but no success, I think due to the nested type it's not working

```
//service.ts
getRecentBackups();
{
  return this.http.get<any[]>(
    `${environment.URL}`
  );
}

getAccounts(accountId);
{
  return this.http.get(
    `${environment.URL}/${accountId}`
  );
}

//component.ts
this.abc.getRecentBackups().subscribe(data => {
  const backupData = data['activities'];
  backupData.forEach(activity => {
    const alert = new Alert();
    //Problem here need to extract response first
    let response = this.abc.getAccounts(activity['accountNum']);
    this.longRunningAlerts.push(alert);
    this.backupAlerts.push(alert);
  });
   //this should execute after above is done.
  this.totalRecentStatus = backupData.length;
  this.longRunningAlerts = [...this.longRunningAlerts];
  this.backupAlerts = [...this.backupAlerts];
}
```

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crxo3g

Observable is returned in console.

Comment: You need to use a switchMap when going from one observable value to the next observable. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: can you please give a bit of detail?

Comment: can you hav a look @Reactgular https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crxo3g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
//service.ts
getRecentBackups();
{
  return this.http.get<any[]>(
    `${environment.URL}`
  );
}

getAccounts(accountId);
{
  return this.http.get(
    `${environment.URL}/${accountId}`
  );
}

//component.ts
 this.appService.getRecentBackups().pipe(
      map(data => data['activities']),
      map(backupData => backupData.map(activity => {
        return this.appService.getAccounts(activity['accountNum']).pipe(
          map(res => ({ activity: activity, account: res }))
        )
      })),
      switchMap(apiRequest => zip(...apiRequest))
    ).subscribe(result => {
      // this.backupAlerts.push({ activity: activity, account: response });
      console.log(result);
      this.backupAlerts = [...this.backupAlerts];
      console.info('Backup Alerts', this.backupAlerts)
    })
```

[Rxjs Zip](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/zip)

[SwitchMAp](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap)

[Map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map)

Comment: an error in the switch map
`The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'.
`

Comment: @Napster Can you create example in stackblitz and share.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crxo3g here you go sir, please pull me out of this.

Comment: @Napster updated example. Now you will receive both value